# Como desabilitar identity com Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

Como desativar o identity no Linked Server para não gerar incremento?
A tabela do servidor deve ficar igual a base local.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ServidorLincado].[BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto ON --Desabilita o IDENTITY

INSERT [ServidorLincado].[BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto (
 [Codigo]  
,[Nome]  
,[Valor]  
,[ID]   -- esse campo é identity
)
SELECT 
 [Codigo]
,[Nome]
,[Valor]
,[ID]  
FROM  dbo.Produto

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ServidorLincado].[BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto OFF --Habilita o IDENTITY
```

Recebo o erro abaixo:

Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Answer (score 0):

A instrução IDENTITY_INSERT deve ser executada na instância em que está o banco de dados. Não é possível definir para outras instâncias.

```
-- código #1
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto ON;

INSERT [BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto (Codigo, Nome, Valor, ID) 
  SELECT Codigo, Nome, Valor, ID
    from outrainstancia.bdorigem.dbo.Produto;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [BD_TESTE].dbo.Produto OFF;
```